# Get the file in a dir that is named with the highest number using javascript in NW.JS

Tags: javascript, nwjs

I am writing in an undo and redo method for some software that is being written in NW.JS. The software adds elements to a DOM.

I need to be able to use “fs” to somehow find a file in a specific folder that is titled with the highest number and grab that name as a variable.

The files that are put into the undo folder are named with unix timestamps so the highest number is the most recent undo point.

I have used “ctime” in my function that retrieves the name of the newest file in that folder but ctime seems to be a rounded number because if I add things to the DOM very quickly one after another, many undo points (files) have the same "create time” even thought there was actually a few milliseconds difference between those files being created.

So, I need to be able to get the file with the highest number from a folder in NW.JS, maybe somehow loop through all the filenames in the folder and do some logic in a loop.

I only have this so far...

```
function getNewestFile(){
 var fs = require('fs');
 var files = fs.readdirSync('./temp/U');
   // need to take each item in this list and remove '.txt’ from 
   // the end of each filename, then turn it all into integers 
   // then get the biggest number as a variable
 alert(files);

 };
```

When I use .slice() I get an error saying .slice() is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
function getNewestFile(){
    var fs = require('fs');
    var files = fs.readdirSync('./temp/U');
    var popFile = files.pop();
    alert(popFile);
};
```